# Xbox One - Programmatically Change Wallpaper

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, xbox-one

I am using the following:

```
MyProfileSettings.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(myStorageFile);
```

To change the Wallpaper on both Windows 10 PC, and Windows 10 Mobile successfully However, when I debug the app on my Xbox One, it doesn't seem to change the Wallpaper. Is programmatically changing the wallpaper on XBox one supported?

Comment: The Xbox One background looks like a theme hack to me.   It is like you are changing the color on the background of the start menu, not the desktop.  The Media Player app on the Xbox One just let me change my “background” – but I do not think that is the desktop wallpaper I am seeing as my new background.  It probably is a simple XAML or registry hack at runtime. Clearly the Media Player App has access to the relevant API.  I hope us mortals have access to this API from our area of the XBBox One.   There should be special badges and places of honor to find hidden apis like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is not yet supported on Xbox but should at some point (no date available)

You can find the list of the not-yet supported features here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt693377